# Copying public folders from a MS exchange server in java

Tags: java, imap, jakarta-mail, mapi

I am currently looking into copying public folders and the containing emails from a MS exchange server 2003 to a local directory in window explorer, in the same structure, so I will then have the directories and the .msg files on my local drive.

I have researched this, but unsure what route to go down. MAPI, Webdav, IMAP, Javamail etc.

I will be creating a Java app to do the copying also. Also open to any other software development recommendations (Perl, C++)

What would be the best protocol to do this and also anyone got any links where I can do some more research on this subject?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

JavaMail can't create .msg files, which are a proprietary Microsoft format, so if that's a key part of your requirements you'll need to look at something else.

If a .eml file (effectively a MIME format file) or a Unix mail format file would be sufficient, you can consider JavaMail.

JavaMail includes a demo program that copies a mailbox hierarchy from one store to another.

There are several options for storing messages locally.

1. Run an IMAP server on the local machine.  This is probably the easiest.
2. Use a local store provider, such as the [JavaMail mbox provider](http://kenai.com/projects/javamail/pages/MboxStore) or another such provider from the [JavaMail Third Party Products page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/third-party-136965.html).
3. Write your own code to store each message to disk using the [MimeMessage.writeTo method](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#writeTo%28java.io.OutputStream%29).

Hope that helps.